# Dashboard Warping

Tags: ford, interior

The dashboard in our car recently started warping around the passenger side airbag.

Should I be concerned about airbag deployment?

Is there a simple way to fix it before it gets much worse?

[image: dashboard warping]

[image: dashboard warping]

We use a sun shade on hot, sunny days but it doesn't seem to be helping much.

I've used (carefully) my car key to push it back down while the dashboard is hot and flexible but it just comes back up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure it is delaminating from its support structure. You could possibly take the air bag out and glue the surface back to its support structure. You'd need something like Gorilla Glue and a boat load of tape to keep it down while it is curing. You'll want to do it soon, though, before it gets too warped. Once it's too far out of shape it won't stay down, or it will be really ugly when you do get it stuck down (with a bunch of ripples through it). Ensure you give the glue plenty of time to dry before you take the tape off or it will pop right back up.

Comment: This confirmed my suspicion, I'm not too bad with a wrench and ratchet but a little intimidated by the airbag.  I should be alright if I disconnect the battery first though, right?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/17193/4152).

Comment: I marked this as the answer. I think for my situation this probably the best route. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @George - What makes you think you need to disconnect the power for 8 hours? The power will drain long before then. Do you think they leave a car sitting at a shop for 8 hours before working on it? Take a look at the link I provided above to get an answer to this.

Comment: I meant 8-10 minutes or so, sorry! That's what most service manuals I have seen say..

Comment: @George - That sounds much more reasonable! :D

Comment: I know. I have no idea what I was thinking when I said 8 hours!